# Как сделать чтобы выводило когда ночь "Сейчас ночь" и день?

Tags: время, java

Как сделать чтобы выводило когда ночь "Сейчас ночь" и день?

Код часов:

```
Date d = new Date(); 
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
System.out.println(format1.format(d));
```

Comment: Определите «ночь». В зависимости от этого определения и пишите код.

Comment: Что выводило, куда выводило?...Эх, хотя бы написали, что это Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хоть так:

```
int hours = new Date().getHours();
if (hours >= 23 && hours < 5) {
    System.out.println("Сейчас ночь");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

1) Определить интерфейсы

для определения сообщения

```
public interface DayInfoMessageProvider{

    public int getCurrentHour();

    public void setCurrentHour(int currentHour);

    public String getDayInfo();
}
```

для вывода сообщения

```
public interface MessageRenderer {

   public void render();

   public DayInfoMessageProvider getDayInfoMessageProvider();

   public void setDayInfoMessageProvider(DayInfoMessageProvider dayInfoMessageProvider);
}
```

2)  Определим их реализации:

```
public class StandartDayInfoMessageProvider implements DayInfoMessageProvider {

private int currentHour;
private static final String NIGHT_NOTIFY = "Сейчас ночь";
private static final String DAY_NOTIFY = "Сейчас день";

@Override
public int getCurrentHour() {
    return currentHour;
}

@Override
public void setCurrentHour(int currentHour) {
    this.currentHour = currentHour;
}

@Override
public String getDayInfo() {
    if (currentHour >= 23 && currentHour < 5) {
        return NIGHT_NOTIFY;
    }
    else {return DAY_NOTIFY;}
}
}
```

и

```
public class StandartMessageRenderer implements MessageRenderer {

private DayInfoMessageProvider provider;

@Override
public void render() {
    System.out.println(provider.getDayInfo());    
}

@Override
public DayInfoMessageProvider getDayInfoMessageProvider() {
    return provider;
}

@Override
public void setDayInfoMessageProvider(DayInfoMessageProvider dayInfoMessageProvider) {
    this.provider = dayInfoMessageProvider;
}
}
```

3)Определить фабричные классы (реализация самая простая и должна расшириться, либо использоваться IoC контейнер):

```
public class MessageRendererFactory {

public static MessageRenderer createMessageRenderer(){
    return new StandartMessageRenderer();
}
}
```

и

```
public class MessageProviderFactory {
public static DayInfoMessageProvider createMessageProvider(){
    return new StandartDayInfoMessageProvider();
}
}
```

4) Клиентский код будет выглядеть так:

```
DayInfoMessageProvider provider =  MessageProviderFactory.createMessageProvider();
    provider.setCurrentHour(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

    MessageRenderer renderer = MessageRendererFactory.createMessageRenderer();
    renderer.setDayInfoMessageProvider(provider);
    renderer.render();
```

Comment: Главное преимущество этого подхода - это то, что когда вы будете писать unit тесты для своего кода, вы можете с помощью Mockito и конструкции when(...).then(...) протестировать класс Provider, сымитировав все возвращаемые варианты.

Comment: @Wial, хотел пошутить про "и фабрику к этому делу запилить", но тут я доскроллил ниже...

Comment: @Nofate: Может, кто ещё не видел: http://habrahabr.ru/company/abbyy/blog/173885/

Comment: @VladD, как раз об этой статье и вспоминал )

Comment: И вот, вместо того, чтобы просто сравнить результат

    Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)

с 5 и 23 пишется такое количество  кода.

После этого кто-то еще сомневается в том, что Java (программы на ней, да и похоже все современное ООП) это ... (сами подберите подходящие эпитеты).

Comment: @avp, Java не виноватая ) Просто кто-то очень сильно пытается в ООП.